# Access Dlookup not return any result in query

Tags: ms-access-2010

Access 2010 my Dlookup function not working. I put below code in my query but its not return any value. I want to get next record in query.

```
DLookUp("[Field1]","Table1","NZ([Meter Reading])=" & Nz([Meter Reading]+1))
```

Comment: How is adding 1 to the `Meter Reading` field going to get you the value of the next record?

Comment: I just want to calculate difference between previous record and current record

Comment: If you are trying to get the previous reading, shouldn't it be Nz([Meter Reading]-1) ? (Assuming '[Meter Reading]' is the record index, not the actual reading)